# How p2p communications works in practice?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I know how p2p communications works in theory:

computer A with ip 187.6.9.1

computer B with ip 137.2.9.4

Both computer A and B have a server program and a client program and they communicate directly without the need of a known server, they may only use it to know each other IPs and after that they can talk to each other directly.

Computer A client sends a message to B's server program then B's client sends message to A's server and so on.

But in practice how this works? I've set a http server in my house before and I had to configure my modem to open a port and receive communication through there so that it was accesible to the world.

So my modem IP was 187.6.9.1 and I had to tell it to forward port 187.6.9.1:8080 to my local computer with local ip:port say 192.1.1.67:8080

But when using a p2p protocol like torrents I don't have to configure my modem or anything. How does this works?

Disclaimer: I'm sure this question has been asked already but I found similar questions about p2p but not about my doubt so I have to search through an ocean of similar but not the same questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Only *one* peer out of A and B needs to be able to receive incoming connections. The other peer makes an outbound connection, and their gateway automatically allows responses to come back in, as long as they belong to the same connection (i.e. same TCP ports, etc.) This is the same as when you're connecting to a website – you don't have to configure port-forwarding to allow the HTTP responses back in. (In other words, the gateway's NAT is "stateful".)
- Many home gateways support automatic configuration of port-forwarding rules via UPnP-IGD or NAT-PMP protocols. Most P2P software will automatically do the necessary configuration through UPnP-IGD – if you check your modem it might actually show the rules that your BitTorrent client has added.
- As mentioned, gateways already have to automatically allow reply packets that correspond to connections you've initiated. Even if neither peer has port-forwarding configured, they can first meet through a central server, then cooperate to trick both of their gateways into thinking that packets arriving at *both* peers are "reply" packets; see [NAT hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)) and [related article](https://tailscale.com/blog/how-nat-traversal-works/). This is commonly used by VoIP software.
- With IPv6, each peer already has a unique address that other peers can directly send packets to, technically making port-forwarding unnecessary. (It may still require you to open the port through the router's *firewall,* though, but while the configuration is very similar, the reason is different.)

Comment: Thanks! I want to program a TCP p2p software just for learning, so I need to do that "reply" packet trick to get it working? Before reading the articles you mention I imagine it goes something like this: computer A announces IP:port 187.6.9.1:9876 to known server C and B does the same 137.2.9.4:7938. Then A gets B IP:port and send it a message? TCP "hello" to 137.2.9.4:7938? But when I make a TCP server I need to specify a port beforehand like 8081. How the modem maps that to A's 9876? Also are the temporary ports randomly assigned?

Comment: The article you share is exactly what I needed and it talks about my questions in here "you can’t reconfigure the router in your favorite coffee shop, or at the airport". Thanks a lot